# Node fetch loop too slow

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api, httpresponse

I have an API js file which I call with a POST method, passing in an array of objects which each contains a site URL (about 26 objects or URLs) as the body, and with the code below I loop through this array (`sites`) , check if each object URL returns a JSON by adding to the URL the `"/items.json"` , if so push the JSON content into another final array `siteLists` which I send back as response.

The problem is for just 26 URLs, this API call takes more than **5 seconds** to complete, am I doing it the wrong way or is it just the way `fetch` works in Node.js?

`const sites` content looks like:

> [{label: "JonLabel", name: "Jon", url: "jonurl.com"},{...},{...}]

Code is:

```
export default async (req, res) => {

    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const body = JSON.parse(req.body)

        const sites = body.list  // this content shown above
        var siteLists = []
        
        if (sites?.length > 0){
            
            var b=0, idd=0
            while (b < sites.length){

                let url = sites?.[b]?.url

                if (url){

                    let jurl = `${url}/items.json`

                    try {
                        let fUrl = await fetch(jurl)
                        let siteData = await fUrl.json()
                
                        if (siteData){
                            let items = []
                            let label = sites?.[b]?.label || ""
                            let name = sites?.[b]?.name || ""
                            let base = siteData?.items
                        
                            if(base){
                                var c = 0
                                while (c < base.length){
                                    let img = base[c].images[0].url
                                    let titl = base[c].title

                                    let obj = {
                                        url: url,
                                        img: img,
                                        title: titl
                                    }
                                    items.push(obj)
                                    c++
                                }
                                let object = {
                                    id: idd,
                                    name: name,
                                    label: label,
                                    items: items
                                }
                                
                                siteLists.push(object)
                                idd++
                            }

                        }
                        
                    }catch(err){
                        //console.log(err)
                    }
                }
            
            b++
        }

        res.send({ sites: siteLists })
    }
res.end()
}
```

**EDIT: (solution?)**
So it seems the code with promises as suggested below and marked as the solution works in the sense that is faster, the funny thing tho is it still takes more than 5 secs to load and still throws a error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Time-out)

since Vercel, where the app is hosted passed to a max timeout of 5 secs for serverless functions, therefore never loading the content in the response. Locally, where I got no timeout limits is visibly faster to load, but it surprises me that such a query takes so long to complete where it should be a matter of ms.

Comment: You are calling these calls sequentially, why dont you call them in parallel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `await` is a great sugar, sometimes it's better to stick with `then`

```js
export default async (req, res) => {
    if (req.method === 'POST') {
        const body = JSON.parse(req.body)
        const sites = body.list  // this content shown above
        const siteListsPromises = []
        if (sites?.length > 0){
            var b=0
            while (b < sites.length){
                let url = sites?.[b]?.url
                if (url) {
                    let jurl = `${url}/items.json`
                    // #1
                    const promise = fetch(jurl)
                        // #2
                        .then(async (fUrl) => {
                            let siteData = await fUrl.json()
                            if (siteData){
                                ...
                                return {
                                    // #3
                                    id: -1,
                                    name: name,
                                    label: label,
                                    items: items
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        // #4
                        .catch(err => {
                            // console.log(err)
                        })
                    siteListsPromises.push(promise)
                }
                b++
            }
        }
        // #5
        const siteLists = (await Promise.all(siteListsPromises))
            // #6
            .filter(el => el !== undefined)
            // #7
            .map((el, i) => ({ id: i, ...el }))
        res.send({ sites: siteLists })
    }
    res.end()
}
```

Look for `// #N` comments in the snippet.

1. Don't `await` for requests to complete. Instead iterate over `sites` and send all requests at once
2. Chain `json()` and `siteData` processing after the `fetch` with `then`. And should your processing of `siteData` be more computational heavy it'd have even more sense to do so, instead of performing all of it only after all promises resolve.
3. If you (or someone on your team) have some troubles with understanding closures, don't bother setting the `id` of `siteData` elements in the cycle. I won't dive in this, but will address it further.
4. use `.catch()` instead of `try{}catch(){}`. Because without `await` it won't work.
5. `await` results of all requests with the `Promise.all()`
6. filter out those where `siteData` was falsy
7. finally set the `id` field.

Comment: Awesome thanks for your reply. I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" does it have something to do with point #6 ?

Comment: console.log(siteListsPromises) right before the #5 correctly logs: [
  Promise { <pending> }, Promise { <pending> }, ... 24 more ]

Comment: 1) Plz, be more specific. Not only the error, but the line too. I've fixed a bug, but it shouldn't be the one you are taking about. The part after `await Promise.all` is working for me, So maybe the bug is somewhere else.
2) Also SO is not about debugging your code for you. It's about answering questions. Just place a breakpoint or a `console.log` and you'll find the problem. Still, if you'll make a minimal reproducible example and paste it in some sandbox, I'll be able to debug it. But guessing is not a good idea.

Comment: well, the code I posted IS a reproducible example, is actually the entire code, if you just use the dummy content I provided (    [{label: "JonLabel", name: "Jon", url: "jonurl.com"},{...},{...}]    ) you'll see you're code doesn't work.

Comment: and debugging it, I can confirm you is the .map you used at #7 throwing the error, so the filter you used at #6 seems to be not working properly somehow

Comment: I didn't notice you modified the .map part, with the modification to the .map you made I just tested and it works! thank you

Answer (score 3):

The biggest problem I see here is that you appear to be `await`ing for one `fetch` to complete before you loop through to start the next `fetch` request, effectively running them **serially**.  If you rewrote your script to run all of the simultaneously in **parallel**, you could push each request sequentially into a [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and then process the results when they return.

Think of it like this-- if each request took a second to complete, and you have 26 requests, and you wait for one to complete before starting the next, it will take 26 seconds altogether.  However, if you run them each all together, if they still each take only one second to complete the whole thing altogether will take just one second.

An example in psuedocode--

**You want to change this:**

```
const urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];

for (let url of urls) {
    const result = await fetch(url);
    process(result)
}
```

**...into this:**

```
const urls = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];

const requests = [];

for (let url of urls) {
    requests.push(fetch(url));
}

Promise.all(requests)
    .then(
        (results) => results.forEach(
            (result) => process(result)
        )
    );
```

Comment: thank you!! I'll look into this and how to readapt my code to use a promise

Comment: this is the right approach, but note that the first part of this code could be written much more cleanly as `const requests = urls.map(fetch)`